# Memory unmapped without a syscall?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

I am trying to find out what is unmapping memory in my application. When I read `/proc/<pid>/maps` I can observe a big region (this was `mmaped` using 128 MB chunks but is displayed as single region). Then, when I print the memory maps after 1 seconds I see that <strike>only some small portions of this big region are mapped</strike>. However, despite using `strace -f` on the application I can't figure out which syscalls are unmapping this; there's no `munmap`/`mremap` that would concern the memory range. There are few `brk` calls but that's a different part of memory, too.

I went through all the syscalls invoked around that time and nothing stroke me; is there anything that could make kernel unmap the memory indirectly?

**EDIT**: My error, the memory was not unmapped, it was just mapped as `PROT_NONE` using regular `mmap` syscalls. I have accidentally omitted the printout of these in a script calculating the sizes of regions.
This question can be closed.

Comment: I speculate that you may be catching a glimpse of the action of the dynamic loader.  One of the things it will do (for a dynamically-linked application) is map the various segments of the application's shared objects into memory.  This happens outside the control flow of the application itself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Isn't the dynamic loader working in userspace, though? I should see anything it does in the strace, shouldn't I?

Comment: Note that the memory region is mapped from application code.

Comment: Yes, the dynamic loader works in userspace, but as I said, outside the control flow of the application itself.  I am uncertain whether you can expect to see all of its actions in your strace, though in my experience, one does see at least some of them.  I refer you to the first words of my previous comment: "*I speculate*".